# verbose map shows the mapping but not the source file it is defined

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, lazyvim

I use Neovim 0.8.3 with LazyVim setup.

In my setup, line movement commands such as `j` and `k` move cursor from one displayed line to another displayed line. I checked the mapping of these letters with `verbose`:

```
:verbose nmap j
n  j           * v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j'
    Last set from Lua
```

The response shows that indeed `j` letter has been mapped to `gj`. I want to disable this mapping. How can I disable that mapping? I tried the following which didn't have any effect:

```
nnoremap j j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems not configurable.

It is defined in `nvim-data/nvim-data/lazy/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/config/keymaps.lua` on line 17.

But you can override it by changing: `nvim/lua/config/keymaps.lua`

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "j", "j", { silent = true })
```